# How to remove or labels to google contacts using people api?

Tags: python, google-people-api

How would you add a label or delete it from google contacts using the people api python library? I can not find much python reference for using google api, I know that you can add a label if you include it in a contact via adding or updating it but I can not find a method to remove it directly or update it.

Answer (score 1):

Google people API does not provide a direct method to remove a label.
to add a label, you can include it when adding or updating a contact. to remove a label, you might need to fetch the contact, modify the labels in the fetched data, and then update the contact with the modified data.